# Cannot receive the OTA version Tania Borealis

Tags: google-project-tango

My Tango tablet had just upgraded to Qianru version by OTA, but cannot receive the new OTA for Tania Borealis, could anyone help to point out the reason? How to fix it?

Thanks
Lucas

Comment: thanks for your reply, looks like for latest two SDK releases ,there are no need to do OTA for device, latest OTA is Qianru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try updating the Tango Core app using the Play Store. You might have to disable then delete it first.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, for latest two SDK releases ,there are no need to do OTA for device, latest OTA is Qianru

Answer (score 0):

the latest versions of software is on this page as well as google play
https://developers.google.com/tango/downloads

latest build is unukalhai
tango core is version 1.42:2016.8.22-unukalhai-release-0-g13e1d179:190011200:stable

as far as i know there was no OTA.

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, for latest two SDK releases ,there are no need to do OTA for device, latest OTA is Qianru